# Is there any Android app in Play Store that supports the dynamic delivery feature?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I want to develop an android app that supports [dynamic delivery feature](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery). Although this feature was announced last year, it's still on beta and I couldn't find any real app that uses this technology. Does anybody know any real android app on Play Store that has an on-demand module?

There are lots of [news](https://developer.android.com/stories/apps/duolingo) about app bundle, but it's limited to CPU architecture, the display density, and the languages.

Comment: Look at Paytm and indian E-commerce company which has over 100 million users for their Android Application. They are using DD for multiple features in their App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [Netflix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netflix.mediaclient) app has a dynamic-feature module. Its customer service feature is a dynamic module that is not installed by default. By clicking on the "Help" button, it will download and install the customer service module.

I've heard that Facebook has a dynamic module but I didn't check that myself. I will update this answer if I found any other apps that have dynamic modules.

Answer (score 3):

Previously developers used to to build multiple APKs to target different API versions & device types.

But with Android App Bundle I just upload the single artifact with all of our application resources and the tooling takes care of what needs to be built and delivered to the app user base. I was able to reduce app size by nearly between 60% to 70%.

Nowadays many famous apps like Airbnb , LinkedIn, Twitter use dynamic app delivery for its users.

[Have a look at this amazing post on Dynamic App Delivery by Joe Birch](https://joebirch.co/2018/08/23/exploring-the-android-app-bundle/)

[Android developer guide on Dynamic App Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

[How to use App Bundles to reduce the size of the app](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9043-android-app-bundles-getting-started)

[Google Samples Android Dynamic Feature Modules](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features)

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm looking for apps that have dynamic-feature-module which changes the architecture of the app and currently there is no automated way to handle it.

Comment: There is indeed no automated way because each app is structured differently and some coding is required to integrate with the Play Core library. Although it's still in beta, it should go out of beta anytime soon now, and as mentioned by others, several big apps are already using it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps using dynamic features, including some big names you'd recognize, but I'm not sure they have been publicly announced yet. I'd keep an eye on the press around [Google I/O 2019](https://events.google.com/io/) if you are curious, it's only a month away.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat also supports that: https://developer.android.com/stories/apps/adobe-app-bundle